# Image not showing up - rgl

Tags: r, rgl

A year ago the following code used to show an output, but not it doesn't. No error is shown either. I'm reading the package [changes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgl/news/news.html) but can't identify the reason.

```
library(rgl)

x1 <- seq(0, 2, len = 20)
x2 <- seq(0, 2, len = 20)
y <- outer(x1,x2, function(x1,x2) 1 + x1*2 + x2) 

persp3d(x=x1, y=x2, z=y, theta = 30, phi = 30, expand = 1, col = "green")
surface3d(x=x1, y=x2, z=y, back = "lines")
surface3d(x=x1, y=x2, z=y, front = "lines")
bgplot3d({
  plot.new()
  title(main = 'y = 1 + 2*x1 + x2', line = 3)
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your problem and ran into the same problem myself. The issue here is that `rgl` is defaulting to using the "null" device ... and when I tried to explicitly stop that,

```r
open3d(useNULL=F)
# Error in open3d(useNULL = F) : OpenGL is not available in this build
```

This led me to how it was installed *this* time, and I found in the installation log (on the R console):

```r
install.packages("rgl")
# Installing package into ‘/home/r2/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2’
# (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
# trying URL 'https://packagemanager.posit.co/cran/latest/src/contrib/rgl_1.2.1.tar.gz'
# Content type 'binary/octet-stream' length 2558042 bytes (2.4 MB)
# ==================================================
# downloaded 2.4 MB
# * installing *source* package ‘rgl’ ...
# ** package ‘rgl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
# ** using staged installation
# checking for gcc... gcc
# ...
# configure: using libpng-config
# configure: using libpng dynamic linkage
# checking for X... no
# configure: WARNING: X11 not found, continuing without OpenGL support.
# configure: compiling without OpenGL support
# configure: creating ./config.status
```

Notably the `compiling without OpenGL support` part. (I'm running ubuntu-23.04 using wayland, if it matters.)

Looking at the [installation instructions](https://dmurdoch.github.io/rgl/), it mentions the OS packages `libgl1-mesa-dev` and `libglu1-mesa-dev`, and lo-and-behold they were not installed on my system. On a shell (not R) prompt, I confirmed this absence with:

```bash
$ dpkg -l libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev
dpkg-query: no packages found matching libgl1-mesa-dev
dpkg-query: no packages found matching libglu1-mesa-dev
```

After installing them with:

```bash
$ sudo apt install -y libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev
```

(much output), I then uninstalled the R package `rgl` and compiled it again from scratch.

```r
remove.packages("rgl")
install.packages("rgl")
# Installing package into ‘/home/r2/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2’
# (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
# trying URL 'https://packagemanager.posit.co/cran/latest/src/contrib/rgl_1.2.1.tar.gz'
# Content type 'binary/octet-stream' length 2558042 bytes (2.4 MB)
# ==================================================
# downloaded 2.4 MB
# * installing *source* package ‘rgl’ ...
# ** package ‘rgl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
# ** using staged installation
# checking for gcc... gcc
# ...
# checking for libpng-config... yes
# configure: using libpng-config
# configure: using libpng dynamic linkage
# checking for X... libraries , headers              <--- BETTER!
# checking for XAllocClassHint... yes
# checking for GL/gl.h... yes                        <--- another good sign
# checking for GL/glu.h... yes
# ...
# configure: creating ./config.status
```

noting subjectively that it took longer because it had more files to compile and link. Once that finished *and I restarted R* (necessary, I think),

```r
library(rgl)
open3d()
# Warning in par3d(userMatrix = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.342020143325668, -0.939692620785909,  :
#   font family "sans" not found, using "bitmap"
# glX 
#   1 
x1 <- seq(0, 2, len = 20)
x2 <- seq(0, 2, len = 20)
y <- outer(x1,x2, function(x1,x2) 1 + x1*2 + x2) 

persp3d(x=x1, y=x2, z=y, theta = 30, phi = 30, expand = 1, col = "green")
surface3d(x=x1, y=x2, z=y, back = "lines")
surface3d(x=x1, y=x2, z=y, front = "lines")
bgplot3d({
  plot.new()
  title(main = 'y = 1 + 2*x1 + x2', line = 3)
})
```

produced a plot:

[image: basic rgl plot]

Comment: Amazing stuff. Indeed, I did not have those libraries either (Ubuntu 22.04, new install). Now it works. Thanks!